# Visual Studio Code giving error for all my jquery code after the update

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code

I was coding and everything was fine then visual studio code got an update and then it ended up like this and it is the latest update as of the time of posting:
[image]

BTW, I checked the jQuery's file source just to make sure and it was correct.

> Ok, @charlietfl sugessted that I should remove `$(document).ready(function());` it got better but I still end up with this :
> [image]

But I thought that using the `.ready()` was important to make sure that the DOM has loaded fully and then the JavaScript code happen. Are there any alternatives that do the same?

### Update and fixed

after looking at the API documentation of the JQuery I found that `.ready()` function is deprecated should be called like below but it didn't say that the `.click()` method is deprecated but it was also fixed using this other way of using it and it was the ESLinter that was giving me a hard time:

```
$(function () {
    function addClass() {
        $("#div1").addClass("divStyled");
    }
    function removeClass() {
        $("#div1").removeClass("divStyled");
    }
    function toggleClass() {
        $("#div1").toggleClass("divStyled pStyled");
    }
    function CSS1() {
        var padding = $("#div1").css("padding-left");
        $("#p2").html(padding);

    }

    $("#btnClick1").on("click", addClass);
    $("#btnClick2").on("click", removeClass);
    $("#btnClick3").on("click", toggleClass);
    $("#btnClick4").on("click", CSS1);
});
```

Comment: What happens if you change to `$(function(){` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){` ? That is actually the preferred way and it seems the message is telling you not to use `ready` any more

Comment: You seem to have a third-party extension that provides JavaScript linting. I guess you can either follow its advice, configure it to your liking or get rid of it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It was fine until the latest update. after reading the jQuery API documentation it said that the .ready() function should be used like the first comment said and I will edit the post for the rest of the fixes based on the documentation. BTW it was the ESlinter extension which was throwing that error.

Comment: it just worked somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed

after looking at the API documentation of the JQuery I found that .ready() function is deprecated should be called like below but it didn't say that the .click() method is deprecated but it was also fixed using this other way of using it and it was the ESLinter that was giving me a hard time:

```
$(function () {
    function addClass() {
        $("#div1").addClass("divStyled");
    }
    function removeClass() {
        $("#div1").removeClass("divStyled");
    }
    function toggleClass() {
        $("#div1").toggleClass("divStyled pStyled");
    }
    function CSS1() {
        var padding = $("#div1").css("padding-left");
        $("#p2").html(padding);

    }

    $("#btnClick1").on("click", addClass);
    $("#btnClick2").on("click", removeClass);
    $("#btnClick3").on("click", toggleClass);
    $("#btnClick4").on("click", CSS1);
});
```